# Prove or disprove the inequality $\tan x \geq x + x^3$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given the inequality $\tan x \geq x + x^3$. Prove or disprove it.

$x \in (0, \pi/2)$.

Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: try $$x=\frac{3\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacLaurin series of $\tan$ is given by
$$\tan(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \cdots$$
Hence taking the difference $x^3 + x - \tan(x)$ becomes
$$\frac{2x^3}{3} - \frac{2x^5}{15} - \cdots$$
You could then suspect that for small $x$ (especially when $x^3 \gg x^5$), we will have that $x^3 +x > \tan(x)$.

For example $x = \pi/6$ gives you that:

- $x^3 + x = \pi/6 + \pi^3/216 \approx 0.66715$
- $\tan(x) = \tan (\pi/6) = 1/\sqrt{3} \approx 0.55735$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

$$\tan(x)=1$$

$$x+x^3 > 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functions $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $g(x)=(1+x^2)\cos x$.

They both are continuous functions on $(0,\pi/2]$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)$.

$f(x)$ is decreasing in a right neighbourhood of zero, while $g(x)$ is increasing.

On the other hand, $f(\pi/2)>g(\pi/2)$, hence there is some $\xi\in(0,\pi/2)$ such that $f(\xi)=g(\xi)$.

By rearranging, you get that your inequality cannot hold on $(0,\pi/2)$,
 since $\tan(x)-(x+x^3)$ has a sign change in a neighbourhood of $\xi$.